# Issues when combining if with loop

Tags: vba

Folks - I've tested this a bunch and can't seem to resolve the issues:

1. If statement responds the same with /true or vbchecked i.e. if I check January, it updates all 12 months. If I check September, same result - all months are updated.
2. Depending on the month I pick, the values are brought in at a different place in "2017 Actuals" sheet. If I pick January, they're brought in starting column 2 (i+1) but if I select April, the values will be brought in January to December but column 5 (i+4).

The argument I have below should only run for the month that the user has checked off on userform.

```
Private Sub UpdateActuals_Click()
Dim p As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 12
    If Me.Controls("Month" & i).Value = True Then
        For p = 1 To 12
            Dim wkb As Workbook
            Dim wks As Worksheet
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
            Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Me.Controls("Location" & p))
            Set wks = wkb.Sheets("Training1")
            wks.Range("Start:Finish").Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2017 Actuals").Cells(5, i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wkb.Close
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        i = i + 1
        Next p
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If you delete the `For p = 1 To 12`, `i = i + 1` and `Next p` statements, and change `"Location" & p` to `"Location" & i`, does it then work?

Comment: Or does it work if you change `For p = 1 To 12` to `For p = 1 To i` and delete the `i = i + 1` line, and possibly change `Cells(5, i + 1)` to `Cells(5, p + 1)`?

Comment: First one worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!